# Vim inserting _viminfo files after every save

Tags: windows, vim, vi

I just did a clean (re)install of Vim (Downloaded from [vim.org/download.php](http://vim.org/download.php), used the gvim73_46.exe installer. Version is 7.3 (patches 1-46)

The only changes to my _vimrc are to set line numbers, lines, columns, and enable syntax.

Everytime I edit a file with vim, save it and close it (`:wq`), a *new* _viminfo file is created in that files directory.

Also, the backup `*.*~` files and `.swp` files persist, and arn't cleared upon saving. Running Windows 7 enterprise.

This really clutters everything - and is a pain trying to open a file for which a `.swp` file exists..
Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

disable viminfo file:

```
set viminfo="NONE"
```

disable swap file:

```
set noswf
```

disable backup :

```
set nobk
set nowb
```

more details:

```
:h 'swf'
:h 'bk'
:h 'wb'
:h 'viminfo'
```

Comment: @ColinMartell the vim & vim-help are awesome. :)

Comment: Isn't that just curing the symptoms vs. solving the root cause of the problem? I wouldn't trust that installation when something odd like this happens.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I've never had to do that and I can tell you I've installed Vim a LOTS of times. Is that a bug ?

Answer (score 1):

That's strange; the *viminfo* file should be written in your home directory, nowhere else:

> - The default name of the viminfo file is "$HOME/.viminfo" for Unix and OS/2,
>     "s:.viminfo" for Amiga, "$HOME_viminfo" for MS-DOS and Win32.  For the last
>     two, when $HOME is not set, "$VIM_viminfo" is used.  When $VIM is also not
>     set, "c:_viminfo" is used.  For OS/2 "$VIM/.viminfo" is used when $HOME is
>     not set and $VIM is set.

It appears as if your `%HOME%` variable (or the `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`) isn't properly set.